# COUNT instances of a text appearing in a range (within a string of said range)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

**E.g. Number of instances where "Distribution" appears in AN:AN.
AN column contains, for example, "134 Distribution Dept".**

I want to count this **since it contains** the "Distribution" in it somewhere.

Note that "134 Distribution Dept" may not always have the same **number of characters** so it may be: "13774 Distribution Department as well"

I have tried using SEARCH() and COUNTIF(), but they have given me errors, but i suspect these are not the correct way to go anyway so I gave up on them

Comment: Would `MATCH("Distribution";AN:AN)` do the job?

Comment: Is this on google sheets or Excel? ALso, could distribution occur multiple times in a cell? And, what if it's part of a longer word? Would you still want to count it, e.g. 'Misdistribution', 'redistribution', 'distributional' etc? In other words, would you be concerned about false positives?

Comment: If you want to count the cells containing `Distribution` case-sensitively i.e. `Distr<>distr` you could use e.g. `=COUNT(FIND("Distribution",AN2:AN11))`. Be more accurate with what you actually need i.e. add more detail, some sample data as text, and maybe a screenshot of the sheet to your post.

Comment: The Count(Find just seems to return 0 even though it exists in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw in a first interpretation of your question, assuming the use of Google Sheets *and* the following requirements (considering variable s to hold the string of interest):

- s could occur more than once in a cell and should be counted as such accordingly;
- Case-insensitive matching of s;
- Prevent false positives where s is a substring of a larger substring containing s (e.g. 'Misdistribution', 'redistribution', 'distributional' etc.).

Therefor, I used:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(LET(s,"distribution",SUM(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(TOCOL(A:A,3),"(?i)\b("&s&")\b|.","$1"))/LEN(s))))
```

Comment: That looks so complicated it could do with a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So, a different take:

[image]

Note I looked for "tribut" as that is common to all the variations of distrbution plurals etc

Comment: If you are that flexible, why not just `SEARCH()` for 'distribution'? Do you not fear the odds of 'Attribute' or 'tribute'? In other words, if you'd allow for false positives, then at least try to minimize them right?

Comment: @JvdV so add as many letters as you feel necessary - but what about the issues where some users fail to spell correctly? distribtion etc I wanted to show a method that could be tailored to suit and it is sufficiently succinct it just about explains itself. How is the explanation for yours?